# Import data from an Access database into Word

Tags: ms-word, ms-access-2007

I have created a program that runs off of an Access database on the company server. The program is running fine and I am about to release it to the office. Before I do this I would like to write a help file in case the users run into issues. However, I am running into problems here. In the program, each user has a security level that is retrieved from the database that allows them to have access to different features in the program. I would prefer that only certain users know about some of the features. In writing a help file for all of the features, I would like to have Microsoft Word read the security level from the database and only display the portions of the help file corresponding to the features the user has access to. I have tried using the following VBA code in the Document_Open event:

```
    Set db = OpenDatabase(databasePath, False, False, databasePassword)
```

But I get an invalid password error (the database is password protected). I have verified the correct password several times now and still no luck. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Is there some other way to connect to an Access database using Word?

Comment: You're probably better off writing two separate documents, and providing the "advanced" one only to the advanced users.

Comment: I considered that, but the only problem is if the permissions for a user change I would have to supply them with a new help file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not include the help in a table with a rich text memo? Each section can be contained in a different record.

When creating such a table I generally have a help button that opens the relevant section and an extra field to allow annotation.

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't even think of that. It would be way easier than messing with Word. Thanks!